# Combine dates with delimiter

Tags: microsoft-excel, combine

I'm trying to combine four cells with dates into one with + as a delimiter.  Some of the cells are empty.  I tried the `textjoin` function but  Excel returns a date for the empty cells.

Cell one contains `23.8.2016`, cell 2 `08.06.2016`, cell 3 `29.9.1999` but cell four is empty.  My function is

```
=TEXTJOIN("+";TRUE;TEXT(N2;"dd.mm.yyyy");TEXT(U2;"dd.mm.yyyy");TEXT(AB2; "dd.mm.yyyy");TEXT(AI2;"dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

but the formula gives me

```
23.8.2016+08.06.2016+29.9.1999+00.01.1900
```

Is there a way around this - or another formula I can use - thanks for response

Answer (score 1):

Change your format code:

```
"dd.mm.yyyy;;;"
```

This will return a blank if the cell does not contain a positive number (which would be a date, in this case), which will then be ignored by `TEXTJOIN`

e.g:

```
=TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,TEXT(N2,"dd.mm.yyyy;;;"),TEXT(U2,"dd.mm.yyyy;;;"),TEXT(AB2, "dd.mm.yyyy;;;"),TEXT(AI2,"dd.mm.yyyy;;;"))
```

Comment: Nice use of the `...;;;` custom formatting mask.

Answer (score 0):

Have your formula skip cells with no value. here is one way:

```
=TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,IF(N2>0,TEXT(N2,"dd.mm.yyyy"),""),IF(U2>0,TEXT(U2,"dd.mm.yyyy"),""),IF(AB2>0,TEXT(AB2, "dd.mm.yyyy"),""),IF(AI2>0,TEXT(AI2,"dd.mm.yyyy"),""))
```

(note that this method only works if all your dates are on or after January 1st, 1900)